# Get Webhook Subscription Data For Calendly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, postman, webhooks, calendly

I am using Calendly tool to schedule calls in my application. I need to get details of every invitee who schedule a call , but unfortunately the API documentation on their website is incomplete. I have created a web-hook subscription and I am getting my event details but I am unable to get complete details for every user. 
Any Help will be appreciated.I just want to know which API call should I use to get all the web-hook data. Something produced using below link but ,where is its API call?

https://developer.calendly.com/docs/sample-webhook-data

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create A Webhook Subscription in calendly using Curl :

```
$url = 'https://calendly.com/api/v1/hooks';

$webhook_url = 'A specific url where you receive Calendly appointment data in real-time';

$curl_data = 'url=$webhook_url&events[]=invitee.created&events[]=invitee.canceled';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$curl_data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'X-TOKEN: <your token key>'
));

$result=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Hook id

```
print_r(json_decode($result, true));
```

Specific url to receive Calendly appointment data in real-time:

Receive the RAW post data.

```
$content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Attempt to decode the incoming RAW post data from JSON.

```
$decoded = json_decode($content, true);
```